# Binding Angular component with specific type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently working with Angular and TypeScript and I want to know if it's possible to bind component `@Input`s to use specific types?

**Example**

```
@Component({selector: 'foobar'})
export class FooComponent {
    @Input() foo: number;
    @Input() bar: boolean;
}

<foobar foo="123" bar="true"></foobar>
```

When the component is bound, both `foo` and `bar` are `string`. Does angular provide a way to enforce the specified type?

I tried this, but I don't like it...*(it seems dirty and not very elegant)*

```
@Component({selector: 'foobar'})
export class FooComponent {
    foo: number;
    bar: boolean;

    @Input('foo') set _foo(value: string) {
        this.foo = Number(value);
    }

    @Input('bar') set _bar(value: string) {
        this.bar = value === 'true';
    }
}
```

It would be nice if there was something in Angular's Input that could act as a binding delegate; For example:

```
@Input('foo', (value: string) => Number(value)) foo: number = 123;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
foo="123"
```

you use **[one-time string initialization](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization)**. Angular sets value to `foo` property as string and forgets about it.

If you want to use something other than string then use the brackets

```
[foo]="123"
```

When writing a binding, be aware of a template statement's execution context. The identifiers in a template statement belong to a specific context object, usually the Angular component controlling the template.

When you use property binding then value is passes as it is

```
[foo]="isValid"

...
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  isValid: boolean = true;
```

if you want to have enum then you should write something like this

```
[foo]="MyEnum"

...

enum MyEnum {
  one,
  two,
  three
}

@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  MyEnum = MyEnum;
}
```

Other examples

```
[foo]="445" => number
[foo]="'445'" => string
[foo]="x" => typeof x or undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a binding like `fuu="123"` the value will always be a string. But if you bind like this:

```
[fuu]="123"
```

The value will be of type number. 
This means, that the values are treated like in normal JS:

```
[fuu]="true"   -> boolean
[fuu]="'true'" -> string
[fuu]="123"    -> number
```

Comment: What happens when I want to use a non-built-in type, like a typescript enum?

Comment: @series0ne That, I think, will only work if you bind a property of another component, otherwise not.

Comment: @series0ne This shouldn't be a problem. I haven't tested it but if you import (or declare) the enum in the component you should be able to use it in the template.